# Change Navigation View Group Item Background

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I want to change background color of Group item only. I am able to change color of all items or selected items and also can change separator color but i dont know how to change Separator Title Background.

**Here is my code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/main"
              android:title="Main Menu">
         <menu> <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/home"
              android:title="Home" />

        <item android:id="@+id/fav"
              android:title="Favourite"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/setting"
              android:title="Settings" />
         </group></menu>
        </item>
        <item android:id="@+id/sub_menu"
              android:title="Second Menu"
            >
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/more"
                      android:title="more" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

In this i want to change color of Main menu and Second menu.

Comment: Did you solve this?